# div responsivo con boostrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

como hacer un div contenedor de dos div acomodados en la misma columna, que al momento de minimizar al tamaño de un celular los div se acomoden en filas y no en columnas.

realizar estos div de manera responsiva, en el cual el principar contenga ambos y en la vista de pc se vean en uno al lado del otro, y en una vista de movil se vena uno sobre otro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
tengo un   que contiene el div de la descripcion y el de actualizar , lo que quiero es que al minimizar se vea en filas osea primero 1 y despues otro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
que no queden en la misma fila, si no que quede uno abajo del otro

```html
<div class="row justify-content-between ">
          <div class="col-4">
            <h6>Descripción de la oportunidad</h6>
            <p class="text-muted" style="text-align: justify;">{{opcDesc descripcion historial }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-responsive col-8">
            <h6>Actualizar seguimiento </h6>
            <table class="table  table-sm  table-bordered " style="font-size: 12px">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right font-weight-bold table-active" style="max-width: 100px;">Descripción del
                    seguimiento Actual
                  </td>
                  <td style="min-width: 250px; max-width: 280px; "><span class="text-muted">{{descripcion}}</span>
                    <input type="hidden" name="DescAct" value="{{descripcion}}">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right font-weight-bold table-active">Agendado</td>
                  <td style="min-width: 250px; "><span class="text-muted " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                      title="{{dateformatHover fechaAgendado}}">{{dateformat fechaAgendado}}</span>
                    <input type="hidden" name="agendado" value="{{fechaAgendado}}">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right font-weight-bold table-active">Tipo de acción</td>
                  <td style="min-width: 250px; "><span class="{{colorTipo tipoAccion}}">{{nombreTipo tipoAccion}}</span>
                    <input type="hidden" name="tipoAccion1" value="{{tipoAccion}}">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right font-weight-bold table-active"><span style="color:red">*</span>Resultado</td>
                  <td style="min-width: 250px; "><textarea class="form-control" style="resize: none; font-size: 12px"
                      name="resultado" id="" cols="30" rows="2" required></textarea>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right font-weight-bold table-active">Etapa de Venta</td>
                  <td style="min-width: 250px; ">
                    <input type="hidden" name="idEtapaVenta" value="{{idEtapaVenta}}">
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm etapaVenta" name="etapaVenta">
                      <option>Selecciona una etapa</option>
                      {{#each etapasVentas}}
                      <option value="{{tipo}} {{idEtapaVenta}}">{{nombre}}</option>
                      {{/each}}
                    </select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Lo mejor es que ajuste: ".col-sm- .col-md- .col-lg- .col-xl-"  Antes que usar "col-", ya que este ultimo ajusta automáticamente y en cambio los otros se acomodan al tamaño correspondiente de la pestaña.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta usar usar

```
<div class="col-md-4">
</div>
<div class="table-responsive col-md-8">
</div>
```

Comment: gracias me funciono